# Prove a combinatorial identity: $ \sum_{n_1+\dots+n_m=n} \prod_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{n_i}\binom{2n_i}{n_i-1}=\frac{m}{n}\binom{2n}{n-m}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

Prove the combinatorial identity
$$
  \sum_{n_1+\ldots+n_m=n} \;\; 
    \prod_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{n_i}\binom{2n_i}{n_i-1}=\frac{m}{n}\binom{2n}{n-m}, \enspace n_i>0,i=1,\ldots,m
$$
I "discovered" this equality during experiments with Maple, but I have no idea how to prove it. It may have a connection with Catalan numbers but that hasn't helped me.

**UPDATE**

Now we have brilliant proof of this equality. But may be it have purely combinatorial proof? Or proof with Catalan number's properties?

Comment: Maybe we should replace $\frac{1}{n_i}\binom{2n_i}{n_i-1}$ with $C_{n_i}$, in fact, so that we can consider $n_i \geq 0$?

Comment: yes, i'll edit post

Comment: @BrianTung I think $n_i$ should be positive. And what is $C_{n_i}$?

Comment: The $n_i$th Catalan number.  $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}$.  The reason I suggest it is that it might make a proof by induction easier?  I'm not sure, though.  I also don't really know how to approach this yet.

Comment: $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\binom{2n}{n-1}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the generating function of the Catalan numbers the left is
$$[z^n] \left(-1 + \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\right)^m.$$

This is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\left(-1 + \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\right)^m \; dz.$$

Using Lagrange inversion put $1-4z=w^2$ so that $1/4-z=1/4 \times w^2$
or $z=1/4\times(1-w^2)$ and $dz =  -1/2 \times w\; dw.$ This gives for
the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{4^{n+1}}{(1-w^2)^{n+1}}
\left(-1 +\frac{1-w}{1/2\times(1-w^2)}\right)^m
\times\left(-\frac{1}{2} w\right) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{4^{n+1}}{(1-w^2)^{n+1}}
\left(\frac{w^2-1+2-2w}{1-w^2}\right)^m
\times\left(-\frac{1}{2} w\right) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{4^{n+1}}{(1-w^2)^{n+1}}
\frac{(w-1)^{2m}}{(1-w^2)^{m}}
\times\left(-\frac{1}{2} w\right) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{4^{n+1}}{(1-w^2)^{n+m+1}}
(1-w)^{2m}
\times\left(-\frac{1}{2} w\right) \; dw
\\ = - \frac{2^{2n+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^{n+m+1}(1+w)^{n+m+1}}
(1-w)^{2m} \times w\; dw
\\ = - \frac{2^{2n+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^{n-m+1}(1+w)^{n+m+1}}
\times w\; dw
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{n-m} 2^{2n+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{n-m+1}(1+w)^{n+m+1}}
\times w\; dw.$$

The integral has two pieces, the first is
$$\frac{(-1)^{n-m} 2^{2n+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{n-m}(2+w-1)^{n+m+1}}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{n-m} 2^{n-m}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{n-m}(1+(w-1)/2)^{n+m+1}}
\; dw.$$

This is
$$(-1)^{n-m} 2^{n-m} 
(-1)^{n-m-1} {n-m-1+n+m\choose n+m}\frac{1}{2^{n-m-1}}
= -2{2n-1\choose n+m}.$$

The second piece is
$$\frac{(-1)^{n-m} 2^{2n+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{n-m+1}(2+w-1)^{n+m+1}}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{n-m} 2^{n-m}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{n-m+1}(1+(w-1)/2)^{n+m+1}}
\; dw.$$

This is
$$(-1)^{n-m} 2^{n-m} 
(-1)^{n-m} {n-m+n+m\choose n+m}\frac{1}{2^{n-m}}
= {2n\choose n+m}.$$

Collecting the two pieces we obtain
$${2n\choose n+m}
-2{2n-1\choose n+m}
= {2n\choose n+m} - 2\frac{n-m}{2n}{2n\choose n+m}
\\= \frac{2n-2n+2m}{2n}{2n\choose n-m}
= \frac{m}{n}{2n\choose n-m}.$$

Comment: Wow. Very thanks.

Comment: I was happy to help. These real time computations do take a toll on the spirit.

Answer (score 6):

Since
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}\binom{2n}{n-1}x^n = -1+\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}\tag{1}$$
the LHS is just the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Taylor series of
$$ f(x) = \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}\right)^m \tag{2}$$
that can be computed by using [Chebyshev polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html) or the [Lagrange inversion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), since the inverse function of $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}$ is just $\frac{y(1-y^2)}{(1+y^2)^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

We will consider the "circle of pairs" ${CP}_k$, more precisely, ${CP}_k:=\mathbb{Z}_k\times\{1,2\}$, where $k$ is some positive integer and $\mathbb{Z}_k$ is the additive cyclic group as usual.

A colouring of ${CP}_k$ is a function $f:{CP}_k\rightarrow\{0,1\}$. The size of a colouring $f$ is defined as $|f^{-1}(1)|$. Two colourings $f,g$ of ${CP}_k$ (of the same size) can be the same "by rotation", more precisely, there exists $a\in\mathbb{Z}_k$ such that $f((x+a,i))=g((x,i))$ for all $\{x,i\}\in{CP}_k$.

Note that the left hand side of the identity is exactly the number of ways to have colouring of $m$ linearly ordered circle of pairs ${CP}_{n_1},\dots,{CP}_{n_m}$ of sizes $n_1-1,\dots,n_m-1$ respectively for $n_1,\dots,n_m>0$ with $n_1+\dots+n_m=n$ up to rotation.

Before we show the right hand side of the identity is also this number, we take a more detailed look into a colouring. Let $f$ be a colouring of ${CP}_k$ of size $l$ for some $l<k$. For $x\in\mathbb{Z}_k$, we denote the pair $\{(x,1),(x,2)\}$ by $P_x$. Note that for each $x\in\mathbb{Z}_k$, $f(P_x)$ can be $\{0,1\}$, $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$.

We now partition the pairs into $4$ types:

(i) For each $x\in\mathbb{Z}_k$, $P_x$ is of Type I if $f(P_x)=\{0,1\}$;

(ii) For each $x\in\mathbb{Z}_k$, $P_x$ is of Type II if $f(P_x)=\{1\}$;

(iii) Pairs Type III are defined in a way that each of them is one-to-one corresponded with one pair of Type II: Firstly, we mark all pairs of Type I and II. Then, for each pair $P_y$ of Type II, find the smallest $a\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ with that $P_{x+a}$ is still not marked yet, this pair $P_{x+a}$ must satisfy $f(P_{x+a})=\{0\}$, mark $P_{x+a}$;

(iv) For $x\in\mathbb{Z}_k$, $P_x$ is of Type IV if it is neither of Type I, II nor III.

The main observations are, given a colouring of ${CP}_k$ of size $l<k$, (a) although in (iii) we can pick pairs of Type II in several different orders, but it does not alter which type a pair will be assigned; (b) the total number of pairs of Types I, II and III is $l$, and the number of pairs of Type IV is $k-l$. For example, with given a colouring of ${CP}_{n_1}$ of size $n_1-1$, there is exactly one pair of Type IV and it is uniquely determined.

Back to our problem, we take a colouring $f$ of ${CP}_n$ of size $n-m$ (up to rotation). In this colouring we have exactly $m$ pairs $P_{x_1},\dots,P_{x_m}$ of Type IV. We pick one pair $P_{x_j}$ amongst these $m$ pairs. You may notice that we can have $\frac m n \binom{2n}{n-m}$ ways to do it. We now cut ${CP}_n$ into $m$ segments, namely $\{P_{x_1},\dots,P_{x_2-1}\},\{P_{x_2},\dots,P_{x_3-1}\},\dots,\{P_{x_m},\dots,P_{x_1-1}\}$, and glue them into $m$ circle of pairs in a natural way. We order the circle of pairs containing $P_{x_j}$ as the first circle of pairs, the circle of pairs containing $P_{x_{j+1}}$ as the second circle of pairs, and so on. And please excuse me for leaving the tedious detail of showing that this process does provide us a one-to-one correspondence :)

Comment: And wow again. Thanks. I'll try to understand it. My idea was that equality has connection with trees (where $n_i$ is a number of vertices or smth. like) or graph coloring.